# Difference between flutter run and flutter run -d

Tags: flutter

AFAIK, when you run the following command, it runs the app in the debug mode.

```
flutter run
```

But the following command also does the same thing. So, is there any difference between the two commands?

```
flutter run -d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d` lets you specify a run target, e.g. `flutter run -d web` or `flutter run -d linux`

```
$ flutter run linux   
Target file "linux" not found.

$ flutter run -d linux
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
Building Linux application...
```

```
$ flutter run --help
Run your Flutter app on an attached device.

Global options:
-d, --device-id             Target device id or name (prefixes allowed).
```

Command (`linux` part without `-d`) is a `--target` flag by default:

```
-t, --target=<path>                   The main entry-point file of the application, as run on the device.
                                      If the --target option is omitted, but a file name is provided on the command line, then that is used instead.
                                      (defaults to "lib/main.dart")
```

Comment: You can also do `flutter run web` or `flutter run linux`.

Comment: @iDecode how come `flutter run linux` can run? what flutter version do you have? 
`

Comment: @pskink I didn't run `flutter run linux`, I thought it would also work like the other platforms command work, isn't it so?

Comment: I've updated the answer, perhaps that will clear things up